# DataTable - фильтрация ajax ячеек

Tags: jquery, фильтрация, datatable

Пользуюсь [datatable](http://www.datatables.net/), все хорошо, работает.

**Проблема**.

Столбцы у меня 6 штук. 2 -ая колонка у меня у меня в виде ссылки, который при нажатий обновляеть контент текущую ячейку аяксом.

И при фильтрация, фильтр не хочеть видеть контент,полученный аяксом.
Как заставить сделать поиск по ячейкам,полученный аяксом?

```
<tr>

                                <td >'.$row['login'].'</td>
                                <td ><a href="#" class="ip-to-host" title="'.$row['remoteip'].'">получить данные </a></td>
                                <td>'.$row['remoteip'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['traffic_in'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['traffic_out'].'</td>
                                <td>'.($row['traffic_out']+$row['traffic_in']).'</td>

                            </tr>
```

пробовал

```
$('.ip-to-host').live('click',function(){
    var link = $(this);
    link.html('<strong style="color:green;">получение данных...</strong>');
    var ip = link.attr('title');
    var str = 'do=gethost&ip='+ip+'';
    $.ajax({data:str,success:function(res){link.parent('td').html(res);oTable.fnDraw();/*каг бы перерисовка таблицы должен был помочь, но нет */}});

    return false;});
```

**UPD**

чтобы понятно было, [можно здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/8VnAV/) посмотреть в действий

Comment: И в консоли нет ошибок?

Comment: нет, и это правильно. просто фильтр не хочет обновленным ячейкам искать. не находить...

Comment: А функцию фильтра покажите?

Comment: функция фильтраций(или быстрого поиска) - дефолтовая, то есть http://datatables.net/ref#bSearchable

Comment: @Zhukov ,можеть я неправильно аттачу полученный res к td ?

Comment: Сложно сказать, это в закрытой части сайта у вас или можно посмотреть?

Comment: да, в закрытой части. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё оказалось просто - надо пользоваться функцией [fnUpdate](http://www.datatables.net/api#fnUpdate), тогда обновляется ячейка и поиск работает. Для поиска позиции - [fnGetPosition](http://www.datatables.net/api#fnGetPosition). Кстати, уходите от $.live() на [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Вот [работающий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/8VnAV/1/) на JSFiddle.

```
$('tbody').on('click','.ip-to-host',function(){
    var link = $(this),
        pos = oTable.fnGetPosition(link.parent('td')[0]); // получаем позицию ячейки

    link.html('<strong style="color:green;">получение данных...</strong>');
    var ip = link.attr('title');
    var str = 'do=gethost&ip='+ip+'';
    // тут была ajax-функция, в success мы напишем ПРАВИЛЬНОЕ обновление ячейки в datatables:
    oTable.fnUpdate( 'mail.ru', pos[0], pos[2] );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: огромное спасибо.